# Search results for URL or Views Titles

Tags: search

I have pages generated by Views with some page url: e.g. /testimonials.
When I search the word 'testimonials' I want in results page to be shown the link to testimonials page.

How it can be done this feature?

I use Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're wanting to index a Views page in the search result. There's [similar question been asked](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/776/how-to-return-a-views-content-in-search-results) already if that's the case. A solution wasn't marked but the [search by page](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_by_page) module was mentioned. It has a submodule that allows you to index any arbitrary path on your site.